# Подсветка кода на С в VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В некоторых файла перестала работать подсветка кода в VS code (как будто бы какая-то синтаксическая ошибка в коде), однако сам файл компилируется и работает.
P.S. Перестало работать после выноса части кода в .h файл

Comment: Вероято где-то что-то перестало работать :)

Comment: так перестала работать подсвета или просто подчеркивает ошибку?

Comment: @tym32167 нет, суть в том что сама программа работает

Comment: @KoVadim нет, именно перестала работать подсветка, т.е. например выделялись функции одним цветом, enum константы другим, сейчас все выделено серым

Comment: может просто выключили подсветку?

Comment: @KoVadim, в других файлах подсветка работает

Comment: ну так, выключили подсветку для этого файла или у файла расширение неправильное.

Comment: В чем сложности просто привести свои файлы (с минимальным примером) текстом и вашу ошибку скрином, чтобы другие могли воспроизвести?

Comment: со скриншотом и кодом всякий может. А тут телепатия нужна

Comment: Извиняюсь, скриншот добавил @KoVadim. 
Расширение файла .cpp.
Как отключать подсветку для конкретного файла к сожалению не умею, но буду рад научиться.

Comment: Что не так на скрине? Как воспроизвести вашу проблему? [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @kirь в вопросе говорится о си, на скриншоте с++... Отключить подсветку можно, нажав внизу справа, там, где написано с++ (рядом LT UNIX)